# Quebra de linha interfere na captura da expressão regular

Tags: php, regex

Estou precisando capturar umas informações de divs que as vezes são separadas por quebra de linhas, e isso faz com que o operador `(.*)` não capture.

Por exemplo, tenho a expressão regular:

```
<div class="search tooltip box-video" search="(.*)" title="(.*)">(.*)<a href="    (.*)"><img src="(.*)" class="capa-poster" \/><\/a><\/div>
```

E quero que case com o HTML:

```
<a href="revenge.html">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/1leadWY.jpg" class="capa-poster" /></a></div>
```

Para teste publiquei [aqui](https://www.regex101.com/r/lW3hX4/2).

Comment: Deveria combinar, `revenge`, `revenge`, `\n`, `revenge.html`e `http://i.imgur.com/1leadWY.jpg` seria isso?

Comment: Sim @rray .......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que você esta usando php é o que indica o link da pergunta. Nessa caso bastaria adicionar o modificador `s` na sua regex, ao utilizar ele com o metacaracter ponto `.` novas linhas são combinadas/casadas.

Sua regex ficara assim no php

```
$str ='<div class="search tooltip box-video" search="revenge" title="Revenge">                                 
<a href="revenge.html"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/1leadWY.jpg" class="capa-poster" /></a></div>';

$regex = '/<div class="search tooltip box-video" search="(.*)" title="(.*)">(.*)<a href="(.*)"><img src="(.*)" class="capa-poster" \/><\/a><\/div>/s';
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $ocorrencias);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($ocorrencias);
```

[Exemplo - phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4cx6-ht9d)

[Lista de modificadores PCRE](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)